# Hat doesn't shift tabs on profile

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

- Open [your profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile).
- Open [your activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=allactivity).

**On the latter** (and how I think it *should* be):
If the user is wearing a hat that extends into the tabs, the tabs are given a `margin-left` with js so they are not covered.

**On the former** (Which is broken):
The tabs may be partially covered by the hat.

I think this is either a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), or, because [winterbash-2014](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2014) will be (relatively) short-lived, [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: I think it is [status-bydesign] because the hatz are relatively short-lived. You *must* admire the hatz now, because anyway  you'll have much time for tab clicking later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case for *your* profile because of your long name. If we shifted stuff around there, the layout would break. If that's the case, we bail out and don't shift anything.

In most cases (in particular when looking at not-your-own profile, where there aren't all the links at the top), there's enough room and the shifting does take place.

So this is not a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), and it's somewhere between [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) and [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Answer (score 0):

It does (maybe only if the hat is *extremely* sticking out), as can be seen in the profile of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165952/canadian-luke) user or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/172958/kevin) user.

> [image]

Recently implemented or it worked this way?

By the way, [Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded) has a large hat too, but the tabs don't move probably because they don't block clicking the tab.

Answer (score -1):

You've pretty much answered the question yourself.

> I think this is either a bug, or, because winterbash-2014 will be (relatively) short-lived, status-declined

Is is a bug, but it won't be fixed since it is not worth it for the time it stays. On another note, it is good that you brought it up since they can keep it in mind for next year's edition :)